# Producing a random file name, and then creating the file, In C++

Tags: c++, io, file-handling

In my program, I'm attempting to Generate a random file name, and then use fopen to create a file with that name. The process goes as following

1. Create a random file name
2. Check if we are administrator by attempting to create a file with that name in c:\
3. Write stuff to the file

**The function I use to make the random file name is:**

```
const char *RandomName(const char *suffix,unsigned int length)
    {
        const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int stringLength = sizeof(alphanum) - 1;
        std::string Str;
        unsigned int i;
        Str.append("c:\\");
        for( i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            Str += alphanum[rand() % stringLength];
        }
        Str += suffix;
        const char *str =Str.c_str();
        return str;
    }
```

**The function I use to create the file, and check for Admin is:**

```
bool IsAdmin()
{
    const char *n = RandomName(".BIN",5);
    cout << n << endl;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen((const char *)n,"w+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        cout << "File pointer was NULL" << endl;
        return false;
    } else {
        cout << "File pointer is legit" << endl;
        //fclose(fp);
        //remove(n);
        int b;
        for(b = 0; b != 1338; b++)
        {
            char f = 'c';
            fputc(f, fp);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**When run as Admin, The program prints:**

```
c:\9UswA.BIN
Not Admin!
```

How do I get the program to create a file with a name that matches what it shows on screen? and without sketchy behavior?

Comment: What is the point here? Creating a temp file or figuring out if you run with admin rights? For the former, check the tmpnam or tmpfile or GetTempFileName functions. Did you google this at all?

Comment: I said what the point was, to create a random file name and the file to go along with it, primarily, but also to check if the program was run as admin. The code above also displays that.

Comment: Your `RandomName` function is returning a pointer to the data of a `std::string` object that is local to the function. This `std::string` object is destroyed at the end of the function, and the returned pointer is invalid at that point. Why not just return the `std::string` directly?

Comment: Also, the parameter named `prefix` is being used as a suffix. A prefix comes at the beginning.

Comment: @Benjamin I'm not sure, I'm far from a good coder. I will check that out tomorrow when i have access to the code again, thanks a ton! Why dont you submit that as an answer so i can select it later. And I just realized that I called it prefix, I must have been tired. I'll change that to suffix.

Comment: Your function `RandomName` is returning a pointer to a temporary that gets destroyed as soon as the function exits. Also don't call `std::srad()` before calling `std::rand()`, call `std::srand()` only once when the program starts (eg. in main).

Comment: @Galik So remove srand from `RandomName` and put it in `main()` ?

Comment: @JayM. Yes, that's where I would put it. It usually the first function I call.

Comment: @Galik Okay I'll add that tomorrow and update above, thanks for the advice. Can i ask why its bad to call it in a function?

Comment: @JayM. `std::time(0)` returns time accurate only to the neared second. That means if you call the function more than once in the same second you will seed the generator with the same number and get the same sequence of random numbers. Computers are so fast its possible to call the same function thousands of times in one second getting the very same random numbers each time.

Comment: @Galik I see, thanks!

Comment: @Galik The srand(time(0)); was fixed, I'm working on the main issue now.

Comment: I changed the code a bit with what you guys said kept in mind, and decided that I could just use all the code in one function, thanks for all your help! I appreciate it.@Galik @BenjaminLindley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, I got rid of the `RandomName` function and edited `IsAdmin` to include its code, with a few tweaks I was able to get it to work at least somewhat well, the code I ended up with was:

```
void AdminWrite(const char *suffix,unsigned int length)
{
    FILE *fp;
    const char alphanum[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv";
    int stringLength = sizeof(alphanum) - 1;
    std::string Str;
    unsigned int i;

    Str.append("c:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\");
    for( i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        Str += alphanum[rand() % stringLength];
    }
    Str += suffix;
    const char *str =Str.c_str();
    cout << str << endl;
    fp = fopen(str,"w+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
            cout << "File pointer was NULL" << endl;
            return;
    } else {
        cout << "File pointer is legit" << endl;
        int b;
        for(b = 0; b != 1337; b++)
        {
            char f = 'c';
            fputc(f, fp);
        }
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple 
just use tmpnam c api

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

  int main(void)
  {
    char name[40];
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
      tmpnam(name);
      printf("%s ", name);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: tmpnam doesn't guarantee that the file is not already created. Also this doesn't create the file

Answer (score 0):

I think running the .exe created here as administrator would let you create the file.
Run the program not from any IDE but manually from file location and run as admin.

Comment: I did, the executable was run outside of the IDE in Admin mode.

Comment: Try to create this file manually in the same location. If u are able to do that, your program can too.

Comment: When I tried creating a similar file in the C drive, it didn't look like i could, so i changed the source to `Str.append("c:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\");` to try and get it to write to a spot that I'm allowed to, but it still doesn't work, I'm on Windows 10.